# Serverside & Client side dropdown lists

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Server side(html helper) & Client side 2 dropdown menus.when 1st dropdown menu's onchange event fires,Client side dropdown menu fired. then i need to get both dropdown's selected items.

My View

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("BasicManagement", "Admin", System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod.Post))
    {
      //Dropdown ist 1
      @Html.DropDownList("UserId", ViewBag.SupervisorList as System.Web.Mvc.SelectList, "-- Select Supervisor --", new { @class = "form-control supervisors", id = "drpsupervisors", @onchange = "getDistricts()" })

    //Dropdown list 2
    <select id="dist" class="form-control"></select>//<-- District list loaded here

    }
```

Model

```
public class PersonRole
{
    //some properties here
    public Guid DistrictId { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult BasicManagement(PersonRole pr)//<-- I wanted to get DistrictId to pr object.It doesn't come.
    {
      //Some code here
    }
```

Comment: There's no such thing as server side dropdown once the HTML has been sent to the client. It's all on the client end, and the way you add logic to the client end is via JavaScript.

Comment: Give the second select a `name` attribute that matches you model property. Of course you would not get these errors if you use strongly types html helpers and bind to your model properties!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter , you can get values of both by same jquery code.
THis is the code via javascript to get

```
$('#dist option:selected').val();
$('#drpsupervisors option:selected').val();
```

if you are using the form Submit then just give them the same names as they are in Model . Example:
In model you have

```
public int  DistrictId { get; set; }
```

Your select should be like this

```
<select name="DistrictId"></select>
```

and 
in Razor syntax

```
@html.DropDownlistFor(x=>x.DistrictId)
```

Comment: No.I wanted to send that Select dropdown list via Form Submit through model

Comment: then second one will work for you . Just give them the names and submit your form . YOu will get the selected values in your controller.

Comment: THere is no difference between server and client side dropdowns . This server side is called razor syntax which actually renders into html as select dropdown only.

Comment: This is going form submit. then in the actionresult's pr object's DistrictId is null

Comment: Use this <select name="DistrictId" id="dist" class="form-control"></select>
OR this @Html.DropdownListFor(x=>X.DistrictId,SelectList,new {id="dist"})

Answer (score 0):

"I wanted to get DistrictId to pr object.It doesn't come."

```
function getDistricts()
{
  //get ajax call however you're gettting Dropdown 2 data  
  //return a value distID for hidden model
   $("#districtID").val(distID);
}
```

Pass dropown 2 value to a hidden model

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DistrictId, new { @ID = "districtID" })
```